# Are there laravel method like in_array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-helper

I try to use methods in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers instead of old php functions I used for many
year. I did not find any laravel method like in_array.

I tried to use  Str::contains , but failed it. Seems different ?

So any replacement of in_array ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `in_array` seems perfectly acceptable and if it gets the job done for you and is not causing issues then stick with it.

That aside, there is the [`Arr::has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-has) helper, or alternatively, you could convert your array to a collection and then use the [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-contains) method, however that just uses `in_array` behind the scenes anyway.